# CoordinatesToolOptions -> CopiedValueFunction weirdness

Tags: graphics, interactive

It seems that a bug was introduced to the `CopiedValueFunction` option of `CoordinatesToolOptions`, where the function is applied to both each point and the whole list.  A minimal example:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 4}, CoordinatesToolOptions ->
  {"DisplayFunction" -> Identity, "CopiedValueFunction" -> f}]
```

[image]
then select the graph, hit `.`, click on a few points, cmd-C to copy, and finally cmd-V to paste the results.  In v12.3 and earlier, the results are as expected:

```
{f[{1.9977469237363317`, 1.07172248216885}], 
 f[{3.0544814577963066`, 1.0343565736890206`}], 
 f[{3.9488769577893295`, 0.9639652410477328}]}
```

but in v13.0 and later, an extra `f` is applied:

```
f[{f[{1.9977469237363317`, 1.07172248216885}], 
  f[{3.0544814577963066`, 1.0343565736890206`}], 
  f[{3.9488769577893295`, 0.9639652410477328}]}]
```

Any workaround?

```
$Version
(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fix: wrap your real function in another that only works on pairs of numbers.

```
f[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := F[{x, y}];
f[else_] := else;
```

results in

```
{F[{2.034996697606207, 1.0717853945551674`}], 
 F[{3.0111813292665492`, 1.0102637473927896`}], 
 F[{4.001361962067824, 1.0018973066232624`}]}
```